# Change the position of a HTML div object through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I produced some very basic code and wonder how it's possible that one part of the function's body works, while the other one doesn't. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="id1">My Heading 1</div>

  <button type="button" onclick="changecolor()">Click Me!</button>

  <script>
    function changecolor() {
      var domElement = document.getElementById('id1');
      domElement.style.top = 100;
      domElement.style.color = 'red';
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Changing the color works, but changing the position does not. Why is that?

Comment: You could try using margin... `domElement.style.marginTop = "100px";`

Comment: Set the position to absolute, use '100px': https://jsfiddle.net/59ymf7dz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, HTML elements have `position: 'static'` which means that `top` has no effect whatsoever ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top)):

> - When position is set to absolute or fixed, the top property specifies the distance between the element's outer margin of top edge and the inner border of the top edge of its containing block.
> - When position is set to relative, the top property specifies the distance the element's top edge is moved below its normal position.
> - When position is set to sticky, the top property is used to compute the sticky-constraint rectangle.
> - When position is set to static, the top property has no effect.

Change the `position` (e.g. `domElement.style.position = 'absolute'`) as per your needs

Additionaly, the `top` property needs to be a string and needs to have a unit, as per [its syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top#syntax)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked (obviously). One more question, if the top property needs a string, how can this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUZF4p2Tu7k work?

Comment: at 7:40 he is equipping top with an integer value and it works somehow

Comment: @Joshua - I'm not a Mac user.  I'm guessing he's using Safari (I think) on Mac, so that browser is allowing it.  On Windows, neither Chrome, Firefox or Edge respond to "top" being set with just an integer value (or, for that matter, a string value that is a number alone)

Answer (score 2):

style.top is just expecting a string, not a number.

In addition, you should ensure that style.position is set appropriately. The below modified code will achieve your desired result

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="id1">My Heading 1</div>

<button type="button" 
onclick="changecolor()">
Click Me!</button>

<script>
function changecolor() {
    var domElement = document.getElementById('id1')
    domElement.style.position = 'relative';
    domElement.style.top = '100px'; 
    domElement.style.color = 'red'
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Elements with `position: static` (the default) do not honour properties like `top`; use e.g. value `relative`.

Also, you are using a unit-less length, which I think is invalid.